# Is there a way I can keep a socket thread running over multiple activities?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, serversocket

I am very new to threading and sockets in Android. Here's what I am trying to do.

Step 1. Activity 1 has a button called "Connect".

Step 2. On clicking the "Connect" button, the app will try to connect to server.java running on the computer. If the connection fails, it will stay in the same activity. Else it will go to Activity 2.

Step 3. Activity 2 has an editbox and a button "Send". On clicking the "Send" button, the data is sent to the server.

Can I access that same thread in the next activity? If the thread is alive, how can I perform tasks on that particular thread? Any sample code will be very helpful.

Comment: Use background services.

Comment: Actually foreground services might be better, given the time constraints on modern services

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `foreground service` in activity 1 when the connect button starts the socket, actually your service should connects to the socket and service will handle the connection and also sending and receiving data.
after that in activity2 you should use something like `eventBus` to send data from activity to service and send your data from service to socket

this is solution is the best way to do this because all the data and models handling are done in service and you don't have to process responses in each and every activity using the socket.

hope this helps